# CMD won't open in windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, troubleshooting

when I try to open my cmd it says'This app cant run in you pc'
Before it was running well and suddenly I forgot my password and I bypassed password by changing name of Utilman and cmd . Then after that whenever I open cmd I get this error I also changed name of Utilman and cmd back to their original still I get this error I also had reset my pc 2 times It also didn't work. Help

Comment: how are you trying to open cmd? If you are trying to run from windows+R, then try running it directly from the file once where you renamed it and see if that works

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked so I am thinking of replacing those files with new one how can I get those..
1.cmd.exe
2.cmd.exe.mui
3.cmdext.dll
4.cmdial32.dll
5.cmdkey.exe
cmdI32.exe

Answer (score 0):

Check your registry for an `AutoRun` value in either `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` or `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`. If it exists try disabling it by renaming the value to something else and see if that resolves the issue.